# How to read a column value in parse.com without accessing an object or a pointer

Tags: android, parse-platform

By using this code, I am not able to get the 'name' unless I use `objectId = xJ34wEo`.
Suggest a way, if not, at least by using pointer.

```
//Parse Query Initialization 
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyUsers");

//To check the row which has "number"="1234"
query.whereEqualTo("number", "1234"); 
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { 
    public void done(List<ParseObject> employees, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) { 
            try { 
                //xJ34wE0 is objectId 
                query.get("xJ34wEo").get("name") + ""); 
            } catch (ParseException pe) {}
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your post to add any relevant information related to your question.

Comment: Thanks Shaishav. Just Did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the `employee` object with that number?

You have a `List<ParseObject>`, so use it.

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { 
    public void done(List<ParseObject> employees, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null && employees.size() > 0) { 
            try { 
                String name = employees.get(0).get("name");
                Log.d("PARSE", name);
            } catch (ParseException pe) {}
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: marvellous... it worked like a charn... Thanks a lot @cricket_007

Comment: In similar manner, can u also tell how to update column without objectId or Pointer?

Comment: Are you looking for how to [Update a ParseObject](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#updating-objects)?

Comment: yes, but it requires objectId. I want to update using 
query.whereEqualTo("number","7661843701");

Comment: If you already have a Parse Object, then you have access to its ID, otherwise if not, then you have to use the string or build a new query